# Probability question :Buying from one of the shops

Tags: probability

> The probabilities of woman buying a new dress from three shops is 
>   $0.22$, $0.18$, $0.35$ respectively. The probability that she will
>   buy a new dress at one of these shops is
>
> A) $0.50$
>
> B) $0.33$
>
> C) $0.75$
>
> D) $0.2$

Which is the correct solution:

C) $\Pr(1)+\Pr(2)+\Pr(3)=0.75$

OR

$\Pr(\text{Buying only from S1}) + \Pr (\text{only from S2} ) + \Pr (\text{only from S3} )$

$=(0.22* 0.82 * 0.65 ) + (0.78* 0.18 * 0.65) + ( 0.78 * 0.82 * 0.35 ) $

$=0.43$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that here we assume that she will only buy one dress (so should be C). Your subject is not very clear. But assuming the answer is among the 4 possible answer, it should be it.

Answer (score 1):

The question is not precise enough, but I think the intended answer must be C, which assumes the events are mutually exclusive (i.e. she will never buy more than one dress, so you can just add up the probabilities).

If you assume the events are independent (which is perhaps less realistic) then your calculation is correct for the probability that exactly one dress is bought. However, if we make that assumption then it is probably more natural to interpret the question as asking for the probability that *at least* one is bought, which would be $1-.78\times.82\times.65\approx0.58$. But neither of these interpretations give one of the available answers.

B and D are certainly wrong, since they're less than the probability of buying from the third shop, and I can't see where A would come from.